# How to choose right caching technique for Magento2 and how to configure them properly

Tags: magento2, frontend, cache, performance

We are working on a new store and want the site to have cached. I think there are a lot of caching techniques but I would like to which are to be chosen.
Ex: Varnish, OPcache, Memcache, Redis.

Appreciate if you have a suggestion on how to configure them as well, as earlier I have configured OP cache and spent a lot of time to disable it due to more caching.

Answer (score 0):

I am using AWS for my Magento website. In optimization part I 3 types of cache and after that my website is running very smooth and fast.

1. I **Redis for session storage**. I could use memcache, but when memcache crashes it will not restore all the sessions of user, whereas Redis stores it's cache in a storage and whenever it crashes it will restore all the sessions from it's storage
2. I used **Varnish for Page cache**. I am using varnish cache for my Page cache. Right now I have Enterprise version of magento, not sure if community edition gives option to store Page cache in some other storage, but after using this I have figured huge change on my website.
3. I used **PHP Opcache on server**. Didn't figured out if it fasten the process, but since PHP script is parsed and compiled into opcode which then is executed in the Zend Engine, surely it will fasten PHP requests.

hope you find your solution.